# How to get nodes grouped in XSLT 1.0

Tags: grouping, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to group some nodes in XSLT 1.0 but can't manage to get the correct result...
Anyone an idea on how I could get the different `<book>` nodes with name `HP_BINNENWERK` grouped like the desire result is showing?
And is there a way to sort the `<page>` by numbers? So from the 003 to 069?

**BASE XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <PartProducts>
    <PartProduct name="DAZ" code="C" pubCode="DAZ" pubDate="2021-03-16" modifiedDate="2021-03-12T19:50:53.7" zone="GP">
      <books>
        <book code="V" pageWidth="207" pageHeight="270" folios="1-2">
          <name>CV_Cover01</name>
          <Pages>
            <Page id="001DAZCVGP21031600101" name="DPP_001_GPVXQU_20210316_DAZCV_00" nr="1" fullPageAd="false" zone="GP">
              <PublishedAds/>
            </Page>
            <Page id="002DAZCVGP21031600102" name="DPP_002_GPVXQU_20210316_DAZCV_00" nr="2" fullPageAd="true" zone="GP">
              <PublishedAds>
                <Ad id="208050-541647-817428" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="207" height="270" bleed="true" cols="6" system="DPPPROD" materialPath="adv_dpp_ads/Adbase/Ad/72/100208872-01.pdf" uaid="0000208872-01"/>
              </PublishedAds>
            </Page>
          </Pages>
        </book>
        <book code="V" pageWidth="207" pageHeight="270" folios="179-180">
          <name>CV_Cover02</name>
          <Pages>
            <Page id="179DAZCVGP21031600103" name="DPP_179_GPVXQU_20210316_DAZCV_00" nr="179" fullPageAd="true" zone="GP">
              <PublishedAds>
                <Ad id="207381-539404-814747" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="207" height="270" bleed="true" cols="6" system="DPPPROD" materialPath="adv_dpp_ads/Adbase/Ad/01/100208201-08.pdf" uaid="0000208201-08"/>
              </PublishedAds>
            </Page>
            <Page id="180DAZCVGP21031600104" name="DPP_180_GPVXQU_20210316_DAZCV_00" nr="180" fullPageAd="true" zone="GP">
              <PublishedAds>
                <Ad id="207218-539011-814313" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="207" height="270" bleed="true" cols="6" system="DPPPROD" materialPath="adv_dpp_ads/Adbase/Ad/38/100208038-06.pdf" uaid="0000208038-06"/>
              </PublishedAds>
            </Page>
          </Pages>
        </book>
      </books>
    </PartProduct>
    <PartProduct name="DAZ" code="H" pubCode="DAZ" pubDate="2021-03-16" modifiedDate="2021-03-12T19:50:53.7" zone="GP">
      <books>
        <book code="P" pageWidth="207" pageHeight="270" folios="3-34,147-178">
          <name>HP_BINNENWERK</name>
          <Pages>
            <Page id="003DAZHPGP21031600201" name="DPP_003_GPVXQU_20210316_DAZHP_00" nr="3" fullPageAd="false" zone="GP">
              <PublishedAds/>
            </Page>
            <Page id="004DAZHPGP21031600202" name="DPP_004_GPVXQU_20210316_DAZHP_00" nr="4" fullPageAd="false" zone="GP">
              <PublishedAds/>
            </Page>
            <Page id="015DAZHPGP21031600213" name="DPP_015_GPVXQU_20210316_DAZHP_00" nr="15" fullPageAd="true" zone="GP">
              <PublishedAds>
                <Ad id="207854-540913-816617" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="207" height="270" bleed="true" cols="6" system="DPPPROD" materialPath="adv_dpp_ads/Adbase/Ad/74/100208674-01.pdf" uaid="0000208674-01"/>
              </PublishedAds>
            </Page>
            <Page id="016DAZHPGP21031600214" name="DPP_016_GPVXQU_20210316_DAZHP_00" nr="16" fullPageAd="false" zone="GP">
              <PublishedAds/>
            </Page>
            <Page id="017DAZHPGP21031600215" name="DPP_017_GPVXQU_20210316_DAZHP_00" nr="17" fullPageAd="false" zone="GP">
              <PublishedAds/>
            </Page>
          </Pages>
        </book>
      </books>
    </PartProduct>
    <PartProduct name="DAZ" code="H" pubCode="DAZ" pubDate="2021-03-16" modifiedDate="2021-03-12T19:50:53.7" zone="GP">
      <books>
        <book code="P" pageWidth="207" pageHeight="270" folios="35-66,115-146">
          <name>HP_BINNENWERK</name>
          <Pages>
            <Page id="035DAZHPGP21031600301" name="DPP_035_GPVXQU_20210316_DAZHP_00" nr="35" fullPageAd="false" zone="GP">
              <PublishedAds/>
            </Page>
            <Page id="036DAZHPGP21031600302" name="DPP_036_GPVXQU_20210316_DAZHP_00" nr="36" fullPageAd="true" zone="GP">
              <PublishedAds>
                <Ad id="207846-541774-817568" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="207" height="270" bleed="true" cols="6" system="DPPPROD" materialPath="adv_dpp_ads/Adbase/Ad/66/100208666-02.pdf" uaid="0000208666-02"/>
              </PublishedAds>
            </Page>
          </Pages>
        </book>
      </books>
    </PartProduct>
    <PartProduct name="DAZ" code="H" pubCode="DAZ" pubDate="2021-03-16" modifiedDate="2021-03-12T19:50:53.7" zone="GP">
      <books>
        <book code="P" pageWidth="207" pageHeight="270" folios="67-90,91-114">
          <name>HP_BINNENWERK</name>
          <Pages>
            <Page id="067DAZHPGP21031600401" name="DPP_067_GPVXQU_20210316_DAZHP_00" nr="67" fullPageAd="false" zone="GP">
              <PublishedAds/>
            </Page>
            <Page id="068DAZHPGP21031600402" name="DPP_068_GPVXQU_20210316_DAZHP_00" nr="68" fullPageAd="false" zone="GP">
              <PublishedAds/>
            </Page>
            <Page id="069DAZHPGP21031600403" name="DPP_069_GPVXQU_20210316_DAZHP_00" nr="69" fullPageAd="false" zone="GP">
              <PublishedAds/>
            </Page>
          </Pages>
        </book>
      </books>
    </PartProduct>
  </PartProducts>
  <UnplacedAds>
    <Ad id="208165-541998-817817" width="16" height="4" bleed="false" cols="1" system="DPPPROD" uaid="0000208987-01"/>
  </UnplacedAds>
</root>
```

**DESIRE RESULT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <PartProducts>
    <PartProduct name="DAZ" code="C" pubCode="DAZ" pubDate="2021-03-16" modifiedDate="2021-03-12T19:50:53.7" zone="GP">
      <books>
        <book code="V" pageWidth="207" pageHeight="270" folios="1-2">
          <name>CV_Cover01</name>
          <Pages>
            <Page id="001DAZCVGP21031600101" name="DPP_001_GPVXQU_20210316_DAZCV_00" nr="1" fullPageAd="false" zone="GP">
              <PublishedAds/>
            </Page>
            <Page id="002DAZCVGP21031600102" name="DPP_002_GPVXQU_20210316_DAZCV_00" nr="2" fullPageAd="true" zone="GP">
              <PublishedAds>
                <Ad id="208050-541647-817428" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="207" height="270" bleed="true" cols="6" system="DPPPROD" materialPath="adv_dpp_ads/Adbase/Ad/72/100208872-01.pdf" uaid="0000208872-01"/>
              </PublishedAds>
            </Page>
          </Pages>
        </book>
        <book code="V" pageWidth="207" pageHeight="270" folios="179-180">
          <name>CV_Cover02</name>
          <Pages>
            <Page id="179DAZCVGP21031600103" name="DPP_179_GPVXQU_20210316_DAZCV_00" nr="179" fullPageAd="true" zone="GP">
              <PublishedAds>
                <Ad id="207381-539404-814747" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="207" height="270" bleed="true" cols="6" system="DPPPROD" materialPath="adv_dpp_ads/Adbase/Ad/01/100208201-08.pdf" uaid="0000208201-08"/>
              </PublishedAds>
            </Page>
            <Page id="180DAZCVGP21031600104" name="DPP_180_GPVXQU_20210316_DAZCV_00" nr="180" fullPageAd="true" zone="GP">
              <PublishedAds>
                <Ad id="207218-539011-814313" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="207" height="270" bleed="true" cols="6" system="DPPPROD" materialPath="adv_dpp_ads/Adbase/Ad/38/100208038-06.pdf" uaid="0000208038-06"/>
              </PublishedAds>
            </Page>
          </Pages>
        </book>
      </books>
    </PartProduct>
    <PartProduct name="DAZ" code="H" pubCode="DAZ" pubDate="2021-03-16" modifiedDate="2021-03-12T19:50:53.7" zone="GP">
      <books>
        <book code="P" pageWidth="207" pageHeight="270">
          <name>HP_BINNENWERK</name>
          <Pages>
            <Page id="003DAZHPGP21031600201" name="DPP_003_GPVXQU_20210316_DAZHP_00" nr="3" fullPageAd="false" zone="GP">
              <PublishedAds/>
            </Page>
            <Page id="004DAZHPGP21031600202" name="DPP_004_GPVXQU_20210316_DAZHP_00" nr="4" fullPageAd="false" zone="GP">
              <PublishedAds/>
            </Page>
            <Page id="015DAZHPGP21031600213" name="DPP_015_GPVXQU_20210316_DAZHP_00" nr="15" fullPageAd="true" zone="GP">
              <PublishedAds>
                <Ad id="207854-540913-816617" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="207" height="270" bleed="true" cols="6" system="DPPPROD" materialPath="adv_dpp_ads/Adbase/Ad/74/100208674-01.pdf" uaid="0000208674-01"/>
              </PublishedAds>
            </Page>
            <Page id="016DAZHPGP21031600214" name="DPP_016_GPVXQU_20210316_DAZHP_00" nr="16" fullPageAd="false" zone="GP">
              <PublishedAds/>
            </Page>
            <Page id="017DAZHPGP21031600215" name="DPP_017_GPVXQU_20210316_DAZHP_00" nr="17" fullPageAd="false" zone="GP">
              <PublishedAds/>
            </Page>
            <Page id="035DAZHPGP21031600301" name="DPP_035_GPVXQU_20210316_DAZHP_00" nr="35" fullPageAd="false" zone="GP">
              <PublishedAds/>
            </Page>
            <Page id="036DAZHPGP21031600302" name="DPP_036_GPVXQU_20210316_DAZHP_00" nr="36" fullPageAd="true" zone="GP">
              <PublishedAds>
                <Ad id="207846-541774-817568" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="207" height="270" bleed="true" cols="6" system="DPPPROD" materialPath="adv_dpp_ads/Adbase/Ad/66/100208666-02.pdf" uaid="0000208666-02"/>
              </PublishedAds>
            </Page>
            <Page id="067DAZHPGP21031600401" name="DPP_067_GPVXQU_20210316_DAZHP_00" nr="67" fullPageAd="false" zone="GP">
              <PublishedAds/>
            </Page>
            <Page id="068DAZHPGP21031600402" name="DPP_068_GPVXQU_20210316_DAZHP_00" nr="68" fullPageAd="false" zone="GP">
              <PublishedAds/>
            </Page>
            <Page id="069DAZHPGP21031600403" name="DPP_069_GPVXQU_20210316_DAZHP_00" nr="69" fullPageAd="false" zone="GP">
              <PublishedAds/>
            </Page>
          </Pages>
        </book>
      </books>
    </PartProduct>
  </PartProducts>
  <UnplacedAds>
    <Ad id="208165-541998-817817" width="16" height="4" bleed="false" cols="1" system="DPPPROD" uaid="0000208987-01"/>
  </UnplacedAds>
</root>
```

**EDIT**

With this XSLT, I can get the result I wanted (thanks to @michael.hor257k) but I can't sort the `<page>`... It worked in a previous stadium of my XSLT but it does not anymore...
Any idea why?

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:key name="PartProduct-by-name" match="PartProduct" use="books/book/name"/>
    <xsl:key name="Book-by-name" match="book" use="name"/>

    <xsl:template match="PartProducts">
        <PartProducts>
            <xsl:for-each select="PartProduct[count(.|key('PartProduct-by-name', books/book/name)[1]) = 1]">
                <PartProduct>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                    <books>
                        <xsl:for-each select="books/book[count(.|key('Book-by-name', name)[1]) = 1]">
                        <book>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="@*[name()!='folios']"/>
                            <name><xsl:value-of select="name"/></name>
                            <Pages>
                                <xsl:for-each select="key('Book-by-name', name)">               
                                    <xsl:copy-of select="Pages/Page"/>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </Pages>
                        </book>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </books>
                </PartProduct>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </PartProducts>
    </xsl:template>
    


    <xsl:template match="Pages">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Page">
                <xsl:sort select="@id" order="descending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Grouping in XSLT 1.0 is best done using the Muenchian method: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html. You can find many examples of Muenchian grouping on these pages. If you have a **specific** problem applying the method to your situation, post your XSLT attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: P.S. Reducing the example to the minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem would also be helpful - see [mcve].

Comment: Thanks @michael.hor257k, I wasn't aware of the "muenchian" method.
I will take a look and give it a try :-) Now, regarding the XML itself, I already deleted the most of it and the infos you are seeing are needed to understand what I wanted to do ;-)

Comment: @michael I tried the method you were refering and it's not easy to implement (I'm a newbie in XSLT) but it seems to works :-) The only thing is that the sort is not happening. I can add a second XSLT step to get it done, but I thought it was possible to perform it at the same time...

Comment: Your instruction `<xsl:copy-of select="Pages/Page"/>` copies the pages in their original order and your template sorting them is never applied.

Comment: Andy idea on how I could get them sorted?

Comment: You have a template that sorts them, but you are not applying it. --- I am afraid that is the end of my contribution here. I suggested you reduce the code to the minimum. You did not. I am not going to wade through all that.